# How to add HttpServletRequest attribute from JSF when redirecting to a custom servlet ?

Tags: jsf

I am implementing sort of ImageServlet serving an Image, inspired by BalusC example here http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html

My servlet implementation expects to have a parameter "Animal" of type Animal

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("On ImageServlet");

        // Get Animal from request.
        Animal animal = (Animal) request.getAttribute("Animal");
```

My JSF page have at some point a graphicImage tag

```
<h:graphicImage value="faces/image?Animal=#{animalForm.animal}" />
```

My animalForm bean is serving the Animal correctly

```
public Animal getAnimal()
{
    LOGGER.info("Current animal is : " + this.animal);
    return this.animal;
}
```

I know that the `Animal=#{animalForm.animal}` is wrong as it adds a Parameter, which will be of type String and not an Attribute but I can not find the way to add a (Typed) attribute here.

I have also read about more up-to-date way of doing the same thing with omnifaces, but right now I am on an learning curve and I have (unfortunatelly) started by project with ManagedBean and Tomcat so I would need to switch to CDI objects first. I plan to do that latter once I have something working at the first place

Comment: Store that object `Animal` into the current session and then remove it once used for the desired purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to pass an(imal) object as part of **query string** but you will need to

- convert your animal to [JSON](https://www.json.org/)
- and then to encode 'JSON animal' to string conforming URL [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) standard.

**Bean**

Convert animal to JSON string and encode to URL string:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
//.....

Animal animal;

public Animal getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}

//...

String jsonAnimalUrlEncoded;

public String getJsonAnimalUrlEncoded() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String jsonAnimal=gson.toJson(animal);
    jsonAnimalUrlEncoded=URLEncoder.encode(jsonAnimal, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("URL encoded JSON animal == " + jsonAnimalUrlEncoded);
    return jsonAnimalUrlEncoded;
}
```

**JSF page (animal image)**

```
<h:graphicImage value="faces/image?animal=#{animalForm.jsonAnimalUrlEncoded}" />
```

This will pass URL encoded JSON animal to your servlet as `animal` attribute.

**Servlet side**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LOGGER.info("On ImageServlet");

    // Get json animal url encoded string from request
    String jsonAnimalUrlEncoded = request.getAttribute("animal");
    //convert it to JSON animal
    String jsonAnimal=URLDecoder.decode(getJsonAnimalUrlEncoded(),"UTF-8");
    //transform json animal to animal java object
    Animal animal = (Animal) new Gson().fromJson(jsonAnimal, Animal.class);

    System.out.println("My name is: " + animal.getName());

    //...
}
```

Servlet `doGet` method will catch `jsonAnimalUrlEncoded` that you passed from JSF page, decode it back to 'normal' JSON string and convert JSON string to real animal Java object.

( *it was fun writing this since Class name was Animal :)* )

Comment: I'd first ask the question if it is in the same webapp... If so, the 'comment' by @Tiny is way, way simpler and only if not go for a more complex answer (even then, when they e.g. can share a database, passing 'id's' is more simple. But security should never be forgotten

Comment: @Kukeltje, I agree with you partly. Passing IDs is solution but my opinion is that user is advanced and he already knows it. So, not digging into his motives, I gave quite good solution that will work in any case. And it is legitimate solution too. Dont you agree?

Comment: Hmmm... if the user is 'advanced', thos Q would not have been posted. And your solution is technically not bad (although there are sort of duplicates). Regarding the legitimateness (?), it depends on what I would have asked first. It it is in the same webapp, it is technically correct but I'd be inclined to downvote  due to it being way to complex (simplicity is beautiful)